# Scala factory method for libraries with different implicits

Tags: scala, factory, implicit

I want to support Json and Parquet file formats. Client should not care about their implementation, but one must pass a type to identify format.

So far I have two classes with such signature:

```
class ParquetFileWriter[T](val path: String)(implicit val writer: ParquetWriter[T]) extends FileWriter[T]
```

and

```
class JsonFileWriter[T](val path: String)(implicit writer: JsonWriter[T]) extends FileWriter[T]
```

trait that they extend:

```
trait FileWriter[T] {
  def write(items: Seq[T]): Unit
}
```

I want to create a factory class to build class by parameter:

```
class Factory {
  def of[T](format: Format): FileWriter[T] = {
    format match {
      case ParquetSpark =>
        new ParquetFileWriter[T](defaultPath)

      case Json =>
        new JsonFileWriter[T](defaultPath)
    }
  }
}
```

the problem is that ParquetFileWriter and JsonFileWriter needs implicits (which are outside of my control as they arrive from spray.json and com.github.mjakubowski84.parquet4s libraries.

How can I implement factory for formats if they depend on different implicits? I am getting a "could not find implicit value" on compile.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**If you have both implicits** it's enough just to add context bounds

```
class Factory {
  def of[T: ParquetWriter : JsonWriter](format: Format): FileWriter[T] = {
    format match {
      case ParquetSpark =>
        new ParquetFileWriter[T]("defaultPath")

      case Json =>
        new JsonFileWriter[T]("defaultPath")
    }
  }
}
```

**If it's possible that you have only one of those two implicits** try to make `Factory` a type class

```
trait Factory[T] {
  def of(format: Format): FileWriter[T]
}

trait LowPriorityFactories {
  implicit def parquet[T: ParquetWriter]: Factory[T] = {
    case ParquetSpark => new ParquetFileWriter[T]("defaultPath")
    case _            => throw new Exception
  }

  implicit def json[T: JsonWriter]: Factory[T] = {
    case Json => new JsonFileWriter[T]("defaultPath")
    case _    => throw new Exception
  }
}

object Factory extends LowPriorityFactories {
  def of[T](format: Format)(implicit factory: Factory[T]): FileWriter[T] = factory.of(format)

  implicit def jsonParquet[T: JsonWriter : ParquetWriter]: Factory[T] = {
    case ParquetSpark => new ParquetFileWriter[T]("defaultPath")
    case Json         => new JsonFileWriter[T]("defaultPath")
  }
}
```

Now if you have the both implicits this works for `Json` and `ParquetSpark`

```
implicit val jsonWriter: JsonWriter[Int] = null
implicit val parketWriter: ParquetWriter[Int] = null
Factory.of[Int](Json)
Factory.of[Int](ParquetSpark)
```

If you have only implicit `JsonWriter` this works only for `Json`

```
implicit val jsonWriter: JsonWriter[Int] = null
Factory.of[Int](Json)
Factory.of[Int](ParquetSpark) // Exception
```

If you have only implicit `ParquetWriter` this works only for `ParquetSpark`

```
implicit val parketWriter: ParquetWriter[Int] = null
Factory.of[Int](Json) // Exception
Factory.of[Int](ParquetSpark)
```

**One more option is to make selection more type-level** transferring it from runtime to compile time (then you don't need pattern matching at all and compile errors are instead of runtime exceptions).

```
sealed trait Format
case object ParquetSpark extends Format
type ParquetSpark = ParquetSpark.type
case object Json extends Format
type Json = Json.type

trait Factory[T, F <: Format] {
  def of: FileWriter[T]
}

object Factory {
  def of[T, F <: Format](implicit factory: Factory[T, F]): FileWriter[T] = factory.of

  implicit def parquet[T: ParquetWriter]: Factory[T, ParquetSpark] = new Factory[T, ParquetSpark] {
    override def of: FileWriter[T] = new ParquetFileWriter[T]("defaultPath")
  }

  implicit def json[T: JsonWriter]: Factory[T, Json] = new Factory[T, Json] {
    override def of: FileWriter[T] = new JsonFileWriter[T]("defaultPath")
  }
}

{
  implicit val jsonWriter: JsonWriter[Int] = null
  implicit val parketWriter: ParquetWriter[Int] = null
  Factory.of[Int, Json]
  Factory.of[Int, ParquetSpark]
}

{
  implicit val jsonWriter: JsonWriter[Int] = null
  Factory.of[Int, Json]
//  Factory.of[Int, ParquetSpark] // doesn't compile
}

{
  implicit val parketWriter: ParquetWriter[Int] = null
//  Factory.of[Int, Json] // doesn't compile
  Factory.of[Int, ParquetSpark]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer! Did not know we can add multiple context-bounds which is a life saver for my current approach. Could you elaborate more on third approach? The issue I am having with it is that I am trying to use factory for generic types where client only passes format, so the method using factory looks like this: `def getFactory[T, F <: Format]` but then there's no implicit for factory. I tried passing both ParquetSpark and ParquetSpark.type however they both fail. Can you tell the topics to research on this? Also interested in why #3 is compile time and #2 is runtime.

Comment: @Aivaras #3 is at compile time and #2 is at runtime because pattern matching works at runtime and implicit resolution works at compile time. Concept of type class (https://underscore.io/books/essential-scala/, chapter 7) is explored in Scala libraries like Cats (https://underscore.io/books/scala-with-cats/), Scalaz (https://leanpub.com/fpmortals), Shapeless (https://underscore.io/books/shapeless-guide/). Regarding your issue with `getFactory` I'm not sure I understood it, maybe I have to see your code. Maybe it will be easier if you start new question and write your code.